# Using poll() on client and server socket descriptor together

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I need to realize a little TCP server on linux which works like a proxy between a variable number of clients (max 50) and a remote server. This process must open a permanent connection to the remote server, read from it and route data to connected clients and viceversa. 
I'am trying to use poll() function on both accepted client socket and the socket client connection to remote server to avoid blocking on recv waiting for data from the server. 
It doesn't work. I can manage accepted client socket correctly but when I add the client connection to the pollfd array poll() dont wait for ready socket it returns immediately but calling recv it blocks indefinitely.

Can I mix accepted socket from clients and client socket (just one) in pollfd array?

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand well the question then the answer is yes. You can.

Comment: How do you obtain the connection as client? Has the "connect" system call successfully terminated or is the socket still in the "establishing connection" stage?

Comment: The fact that poll() returned, by itself, doesn't mean that any particular socket is ready-for-read.  You also need to check the revents value of your socket's pollfd struct to see what events were returned for that particular socket.

Comment: Btw if you are going to be managing multiple sockets with a single thread, you might want to set all of the sockets to non-blocking mode, in order to guarantee that your program won't get blocked in a recv() call anywhere.

Comment: You are right. Now I know it's possible mix accepted socket and client socket in pollfd array. The problem was the events enabled on the client socket and the "if" about checking the revents.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, my application is single thread, I did not set socket to non-blocking I though using poll() was enough. If I "read" on client socket more data than there are it doesn't block, "read" returns the only chars in buffer, I check it as first thing. I don't know about accepted socket behavior, this night I will try. Thanks.